# I can't deploy my rails project on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, devise

I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails but I'm wondering why it won't deploy on heroku. 
After using `git push heroku master` on Terminal and the bundle is installed, it comes up as this:

```
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NameError: uninitialized constant Devise
```

The precompiling assets failed and the push is rejected as a result.

This is the top of my config/application.rb file:

```
require 'devise'

require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

and my devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  config.reconfirmable = true

  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  config.password_length = 8..128

  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

Let me know if you need more information but I'm stuck. I've installed sqlite3 and bundle installed the gem files but nothing was solved.

My gem file includes all of the following:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

gem 'pg'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'devise'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'spring'

 gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

end
```

Comment: i wished you could spell `heroku` right :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku requires pg to be the database and removal of sqlite3 from the main gem file on top.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add gem 'Devise' in your Gemfile? Does the file included in your repository?

Comment: yeah i included the gem file and it is added in my repo. is there any other problem?